# Is US Patent 6163785 prior art for US Patent Application 20110097693

Tags: us6163785, us20110097693

[US Patent 6163785](http://www.google.com/patents/US6163785) controls text/translations in separate documents within a CSL Constrained Source Language model, applied to generate translations that require no post-editing.

[US Patent Application 20110097693](http://www.google.com/patents/US20110097693), combines text/translation within a single editable text, while controlling delineation and pairing of "chunks" in both text and translation, meant to be edited.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15384569/etc/12925732.pdf contains divergent opinions on the issue.

[US Patent Application 20110097693](http://www.google.com/patents/US20110097693) is a step toward text/translation chunk/alignment controls in one editable text as shown here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIbvJck5JdM and further specified in 13842249.

Is [US Patent 6163785](http://www.google.com/patents/US6163785) truly prior art inherently able to control text/translation chunk/alignment within a single editable document? Thanks!

Comment: Changed the reference to the application to its publication number. The tags don't work with serial numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As I am assuming the poster is aware, US20110097693 was given a final rejection a few months ago. It was **not** rejected as being fully anticipated by 6163785. So even the examiner doesn't think everything in it is taught in that single document. It was rejected under 103 (obviousness) under 6163785 and 6,438,515 taken together. The other application serial number mentioned in the question appears to still be unpublished.
Ask Patents is not likely to produce a full analysis of the OA and advice on how to respond.

Comment: [response](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15384569/etc/US20110097693response.pdf) to preliminary rejection of US20110097693 claims; btw I wrote 6438515, improved it somwewhat with '693 (and much more in continuation with 13842249); the new stuff may seem "obvious" after the fact; in reality it's been quite an ordeal to learn how control text/translation chunks combined within editable textarea.